# Where to find this unpublished Bentley's research paper?

Tags: computational-geometry

Bentley, J.L. [1977]:
Solution to Klee's rectangle problems,
unpublished manuscript,
Dept. of Computer Science, Carnegie-Mellon University,
1977.

Is it classified or not archived at all?

Comment: It's not classified for sure - the Bentley solution is presented in the Section 8.4 of the Preparata and Shamos textbook, and in many other books as well.

Comment: 1977. That is a long time ago. In those days "Technical Reports" were printed and used to mail your colleagues the recent results. With Internet that function is taken over by ArXiv. Not all Departments actually keep track of their Technical Reports. Some Departments keep an archive, some are retroactively scanning their Reports, but much is lost I guess. An "Unpublished Manuscript" has the same goal, distribution to your colleagues, but has a very unofficial status. The author may have abandoned the project, or its contents have been superseeded by another publication.

Comment: Google Scholar shows this paper has hundreds of citations throughout several decades. How have the authors recently managed to cite the seemingly lost paper?